# iptables -i lo vs. -s localhost and -j REJECT vs. -P INPUT REJECT

Tags: security, iptables

## Preface

Just like everything in Linux I'm sure there are a lot of ways to get an intended result with `iptables`. I'd like to limit answers to the following categories:

1. What is the difference between the options?
2. Which option is best (or are they the same)?
3. Why do you prefer one over the other?

And please be clear what category you are speaking to. It's okay to state *preferences*, but don't imply that it is *best*.

e.g.

> I prefer to put `--jump` as the first argument because I think it reads better to have the intent first and I like to vertically align like arguments of multiple commands.

## Question

Is one of these better than the other?

```
iptables -I INPUT --jump ACCEPT --in-interface lo
iptables -I INPUT --jump ACCEPT --source localhost
```

Is one of these better than the other?

```
iptables -A INPUT --jump REJECT
iptables -P INPUT REJECT
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In both cases, the two iptables commands you are comparing have different semantics and behave differently to each other. It's not necessarily a matter of which is "best" but of what behavior you are trying to match or provide.

First:

```
iptables -I INPUT --jump ACCEPT --in-interface lo
iptables -I INPUT --jump ACCEPT --source localhost
```

The first of these accepts all local traffic, on the `lo` interface, regardless of its IP address. The second one accepts all traffic from 127.0.0.1, regardless of what interface it arrives on.

In this case the first one is clearly better. In the first case, local traffic doesn't necessarily use 127.0.0.1 as its IP address but you probably want to accept it, (the best known of these is Debian's odd 127.0.1.1, but it's possible for global IP addresses to be attached to `lo`) and in the second case, someone could send you spoofed packets with 127.0.0.1 as its source address and you probably don't want to accept that.

Second:

```
iptables -A INPUT --jump REJECT
iptables -P INPUT REJECT
```

These are usually functionally identical, except:

When someone adds more rules to the end of the INPUT chain, the rules will not have any effect. The archives here have numerous examples of people confused by this. So you might want to use the second form.

The chain policy can't accept arguments, but the REJECT target *does* accept arguments. If you want to specify the reject reason, or want to give different reject reasons in different circumstances, you must use the first form (see the `iptables-extensions` man page for the list of reject reasons).

Comment: Excellent explanation. I'm really glad I decided to ask this. For the first question, I figured that was the case (though I hadn't considered spoofing). For the second question, I have read dozens of references and never gotten that.

Comment: iptables is probably unique among firewalls in that it evaluates rules in the order in which they appear. If you're accustomed to this, it's no problem. But it's quite a surprise to anyone accustomed to virtually every other firewall out there.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding preference, I setup iptables such that it is **easy to manage & difficult to mismanage**.

1. For non-meaningful formatting, I prefer to note down my rules in such order, that I can most **easily verify firewall status** regardless how simple the tool used. Examining changes should be as trivial as `diff -wu <(iptables-save | egrep -v ^#) <(egrep -v ^# rules.v4)`
2. When two similar approaches under *common* configurations result in the same behaviour, I choose the one that will **express what I really meant** even under *uncommon* configurations. Hence I prefer `-A INPUT -i lo -J ACCEPT` over `-A INPUT -s localhost -J ACCEPT` because the latter comes with an *assumption* (that in a sane setup, no other interface could receive such packet)
3. When 2 restrictions mean the same thing, I choose either both or the one that **cannot be unintentionally lifted**. While the rule `-A INPUT -j REJECT` can be `-R`eplaced, such mistake would not affect chain policy like `-P INPUT REJECT`

Comment: That diffing 2 process substitutions trick is pretty awesome. I don't often think about what you can do with a File Descriptor vs a redirected stream.